# Jackson Convert Object to Map preserving Date type

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using Jackson `ObjectMapper` to convert a Java Bean to a `Map`.

However, it is not preserving the `Date` object, rather it gets converted to `Long`.

Here is the failing test case,

```
@Test
public void testObjectToMapDate() {

    User user = new User();
    user.setDob(new Date());

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, Object> map = mapper.convertValue(user, Map.class);
    assertTrue(map.get("dob") instanceof Date);

}
```

Is there a simple solution to this?

Comment: @sotirios is right. read the [doc](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) to find out more

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Jackson, by default, serializes `java.util.Date` instances as numeric timestamps. You can configure Jackson to use a textual representation with

```
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false); // it's true by default
```

or provide your own `JsonSerializer`.

However, when you are doing the conversion, there is absolutely nothing in the intermediate JSON and in the target type, `Map`, to indicate to Jackson that it should deserialize it as a `Date` object. Without extra type information, Jackson will always deserialize it using its defaults (`long`, `double`, `String`, `LinkedHashMap`).

Comment: Is there any way to configure a custom deserializer to match the regex of an ISO timestamp, and deserialize as Date when that is matched?

Comment: But in that case, it translated the value to String. Eg:2019-11-14T16:04:35.719+0000